# How do you interpolate UV mapping coords in a triangle tessellation evaluation shader?

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, interpolation, uv-mapping

I tried to interpolate UV coordinates this way in my TES without success. What is the right way to do UV coordinates interpolation?
I remark that I'm working with triangle tessellation.

```
#version 450 core

layout (triangles, equal_spacing, cw) in;

in vec2 UV_tcs[];
out vec2 UV_tes;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = (gl_TessCoord.x * gl_in[0].gl_Position +
                   gl_TessCoord.y * gl_in[1].gl_Position + 
                  gl_TessCoord.z * gl_in[2].gl_Position );

    UV_tes = gl_TessCoord.x * UV_tcs[0] + gl_TessCoord.y * UV_tcs[1];

}
```

Comment: Tried but didn't work, as UV_tcs is a vec2, does not have a third component

Comment: You are so so right! Thanks a lot! Works fine now!

Answer (score 2):

In your case the type of the tessellation primitive is `triangle`

```
layout (triangles, equal_spacing, cw) in;
```

and the input variable `UV_tcs` is per vertex (and not per patch).
See [Tessellation Control Shader - Outputs](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tessellation_Control_Shader#Outputs)
and [Tessellation Evaluation Shader - Inputs](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tessellation_Evaluation_Shader#Inputs).

```
in vec2 UV_tcs[];
```

See [Khronos OpenGL wiki - Tessellation - Triangles](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tessellation#Triangles)

> Each vertex generated and sent to the TES will be given [Barycentric coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system#Barycentric_coordinates_on_triangles) as the `gl_TessCoord` input. This coordinate defines where this vertex is located within the abstract triangle patch. The barycentric coordinates for the 3 vertices of the abstract triangle patch are shown in the diagram. All other vertices will be specified relative to these.
>
> To perform linear interpolation between 3 values, at each of the three vertices, you would do this:
>
> ```
> vec3 accum = vec3(0.0f)
>     accum += gl_TessCoord[0] * value[0]
>     accum += gl_TessCoord[1] * value[1]
>     accum += gl_TessCoord[2] * value[2]
> ```

This means the attributes have to be interpolated according to the [Barycentric coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system) (`gl_TessCoord.xyz`) of the triangle primitive, independent on the type of the attribute.

You have to do it as you do it for the position (`gl_in[].gl_Position`), change your code like this:

```
UV_tes = 
    gl_TessCoord.x * UV_tcs[0] +
    gl_TessCoord.y * UV_tcs[1] + 
    gl_TessCoord.z * UV_tcs[2];
```